# Bash alias -=... (alias name should be a simple dash) not working

Tags: bash, alias

I want to create an alias for `cd -` which should be just a dash (`-`).
I tried without success:

```
alias -='cd -'     # bash: alias: -=: Invalid option
alias \-='cd -'    # bash: alias: -=: Invalid option
alias '-'='cd -'   # bash: alias: -=: Invalid option
alias '\-'='cd -'  # bash: alias: `\-': Invalid alias name.
```

The former three are the same (only different input, but bash turns all of them into the same command `alias` with a single argument `-=cd -`), so it's no surprise the error message is the same. I'd guess that if the argument starts with a dash, it's parsed as a flag rather than the alias name.

Is it even possible to use `-` as an alias name?

Comment: Never knew about `cd -`

Comment: @MarcoCeppi Me neither, until today. Checkout http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/browse/sort-by-votes for more nice tricks!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

With most commands, you can pass `--` as an argument, and all subsequent arguments are treated as operands and not options, even if they begin with a dash. The `alias` builtin in bash recognizes `--`.

```
alias -- -='cd -'
```